# Error on SetWindowPos

Tags: winapi, c++-cli

I'm trying to write simple code for changing an application (notepad) windows position. Notepad should be running in background (only 1 instance).

I am using `Process::GetProcessesByName( "notepad")` to get the process ID,
and `myProcess->MainWindowHandle` to get the notepad windows handle.

Now I am trying to change window size by passing the HWND handle to SetWindowPos,

I am not sure how to correctly do it (searched the web didn't find a clear newbie-answer)

1st I tried:

```
HWND hwnd =  myProcess->MainWindowHandle;
             SetWindowPos(hwnd , 
                 HWND_TOP, 
                 100, 
                 100, 
                 0, 0,          // Ignores size arguments. 
                 SWP_NOSIZE);
```

This got me

```
Compile error:  error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'System::IntPtr' to 'HWND'
```

Then I tried casting and passing as reference:

```
HWND hwnd =  (HWND)&myProcess->MainWindowHandle;
SetWindowPos(&hwnd , 
         HWND_TOP, 
         100, 
         100, 
         0, 0,          // Ignores size arguments. 
         SWP_NOSIZE); 

       }
```

Error:

```
Compile error:  error C2664: 'SetWindowPos' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'HWND *' to 'HWND'
```

See below for complete code:

```
#include "StdAfx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>  

#using <System.dll>
using namespace System;
using namespace System::Diagnostics;
int main()
{

      array<Process^>^myProcesses = Process::GetProcessesByName( "notepad");
      if ( myProcesses->Length == 0 )
            Console::WriteLine( "Could not find notepad processes on local computer." );
      Collections::IEnumerator^ myEnum = myProcesses->GetEnumerator();
      while ( myEnum->MoveNext() )
      {
         Process^ myProcess = safe_cast<Process^>(myEnum->Current);
         Console::Write( "Process Name : {0}  Process ID : {1}  HandleCount : {2}\n", myProcess->ProcessName, myProcess->Id, myProcess->HandleCount );
         Console::Write( "Main window Title : {0}  MainWindowHandle : {1}", myProcess->MainWindowTitle, myProcess->MainWindowHandle );

//HWND hwnd =  myProcess->MainWindowHandle; //1st try
     //          SetWindowPos(hwnd , 
  //               HWND_TOP, 
  //               100, 
  //               100, 
  //               0, 0,          // Ignores size arguments. 
  //               SWP_NOSIZE); 

        HWND hwnd =  (HWND)&myProcess->MainWindowHandle;//2nd try
        SetWindowPos(&hwnd , 
                 HWND_TOP, 
                 100, 
                 100, 
                 0, 0,          // Ignores size arguments. 
                 SWP_NOSIZE); 

               }
      }   
}
```

Comment: `HWND hwnd =  (HWND)(myProcess->MainWindowHandle.ToPointer());` Of course, use `hwnd` and not `&hwnd` in SetWindowPos call, as mentioned by @πάνταῥεῖ

Comment: `SetWindowPos(hwnd , ` remove the `&`

Comment: The compiler error is exceedingly clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you send an adress to first param of SetWindowsPos function but this function expect a HWND value. You know in C++ :

- &variable = return adress of variable where is store the value
- variable = return value of variable

Visual C++ Intellisense or tooltip give you prototype.

```
BOOL SetWindowsPos(HWND, HWND, int, int, int, int, UINT);
```

EDIT : as say in comment, this line :

```
HWND hwnd = (HWND)&myProcess->MainWindowHandle;
```

is wrong, you have to do :

```
HWND hwnd = (HWND)myProcess->MainWindowHandle.ToPointer();
```

**ToPointer** method documentation : http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.intptr.topointer(v=vs.110).aspx